# How to make default value with a struct property?

Tags: c#, struct

I would like to know how to apply [DefaultValue] attribute to a struct property. You can notice that Microsoft does it with Form's Size and many other properties. Their values' types are Size, Point, etc. I would want to do the same thing with my custom struct.

Answer (score 12):

```
[DefaultValue(typeof(Point), "0, 0")]
```

Would be an example.  Using a string to initialize the value is a necessary evil, the kind of types you can use in an attribute constructor are *very* limited.  Only the simple value types, string, Type and a one-dimensional array of them.

To make this work, you have to write a TypeConverter for your struct:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(PointConverter))]
[// etc..]
public struct Point
{
   // etc...
}
```

Documentation on type converters in the MSDN library isn't great.  Using the .NET type converters whose source you can look at with the Reference Source or reverse-engineer with Reflector is a great starting point to get your own working.  Watch out for culture btw.

Answer (score 6):

`[DefaultValue]` attribute is for designer/code generator/etc only. You cannot use it for `structs`. `structs` out of all are value types and can don't support default constructor. When object of a `struct` is created, all of it's properties/fields are set to their default values. You cannot change this behavior.

MSDN reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx

### Remarks:

> You can create a DefaultValueAttribute
> with any value. A member's default
> value is typically its initial value.
> A visual designer can use the default
> value to reset the member's value.
> Code generators can use the default
> values also to determine whether code
> should be generated for the member.

### Note:

> A DefaultValueAttribute will not cause
> a member to be automatically
> initialized with the attribute's
> value. You must set the initial value
> in your code.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the property type -- you can only use constant values in attributes, so it would have to be a primitive type, a string, an enum type, or any other type that is valid in `const` context.

So if your property is a string, you would just do something like:

```
[DefaultValue("foo")]
public string SomeProperty { get; private set; }
```

Note that this **will not** affect the behavior of the struct's default constructor, which will still initialize `SomeProperty` to null; this attribute only affects the behavior of Visual Studio's property pane.