# How to make a default value for the struct in C#?

Tags: c#, struct

I'm trying to make default value for my struct. 
For example default value for Int - 0, for DateTime - 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM.
As known we can't define parameterless constructor in structure.

```
struct Test
{
    int num;
    string str;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(default(Test)); // shows namespace and name of struct test.Test
        Console.WriteLine(new Test()); // same

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

How can I make a default value for struct?

Comment: Read similar article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572325/how-to-make-default-value-with-a-struct-property

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can't. Structures are always pre-zeroed, and there is no guarantee the constructor is ever called (e.g. `new MyStruct[10]`). If you need default values other than zero, you need to use a class. That's why you can't change the default constructor in the first place (until C# 6) - it never executes.

The closest you can get is by using `Nullable` fields, and interpreting them to have some default value if they are null through a property:

```
public struct MyStruct
{
  int? myInt;

  public int MyInt { get { return myInt ?? 42; } set { myInt = value; } }
}
```

`myInt` is still pre-zeroed, but you interpret the "zero" as your own default value (in this case, 42). Of course, this may be entirely unnecessary overhead :)

As for the `Console.WriteLine`, it simply calls the virtual `ToString`. You can change it to return it whatever you want.

Comment: That's pretty clever!  As long as you keep in mind that two instances of MyStruct may or may not come back as equivalent, even though MyInt returns 42 for both.

Comment: I had the same issue, but I solved it by adding a hidden boolean flag that would allow me to now if it was a default struct or one created with the ctor. It works as expected.
`MyStrutctCtor(...){ _isInitializedHiddenFlag = true; }`, then if the struct is default I can use any fallback value I'd like. I also use it in comparison methods to differentiate default values for equivalent manually set value

Comment: Agreed very clever. However I find it bizarre that C# structs do not allow some kind of default initialization. Even in C++ this can be done (I know, I know, C++ structs and classes are nearly the same thing). But surely there's no technical reason the CLR cannot allow this. Seems like a huge oversight or some kind of overbearing philosophical decision.

Comment: @PeterMoore I suspect the technical reason is simply that you couldn't avoid running an initializer for every struct in an array, for example. That's a substantial cost for something that's in almost all cases pointless and in the rare case where you want it, you can easily do it yourself. CLR doesn't do a lot of things it "could possibly do" :) Also note that C# has moved on - you can now create a parameter-less constructor for structs, but it still isn't invoked in e.g. `new MyStruct[10]`.

Comment: Ah you have a good point about arrays. If you make an array of struct's in C++ they won't get initialized either. But still, in C# the bytes in RAM *do* get initialized to their default values. And they're not just zeroing out the bytes either because floating point members of structs initialize as 0 as well. So if they could do that, they could let you specify the default. Just my $0.02!

Comment: @PeterMoore They're zeroed out, it's nothing more complicated than that. Floating point numbers initialize as 0 as well because zeroed out memory _is_ a zero value in float ;)

Comment: Huh for some reason I was under the impression 0x00000000 didn't map to 0f but I must have been smoking something. Well then if everything is just zeroed out I guess the lack of configurable defaults makes some sense!

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is not with the behaviour of C#/.Net. The way you instantiate the struct effectively creates an instance with default values for all member fields.

The `Console.WriteLine` converts its argument to a string using the ToString() method. The default implementation (`Object.ToString()`) simply writes the fully qualified class name (namespace and name, as you call it).

If you want another visualisation, you should override the `ToString` method:

```
public struct Test
{
    int num;
    string str;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"num: {num} - str: {str}";
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Printing out objects of the C# results with namespaces unless you override .ToString() for your objects. Can you define your struct like below and try it ?

```
public struct Test
{
    int num;
    string str;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Some string representation of this struct";
    }
}
```

PS: default(Test) gives you a struct contains default(int) and default(string) which I mean Test.num is `0` and Test.str is `null`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public static readonly Default = new MyStruct(42);

    public int i;

    public MyStruct(int i)
    {
        this.i = i;
    }
}
```

And then when you create a default struct of this type do this:

```
public MyStruct newStruct = MyStruct.Default;
```

But of course, this won't override default and other programmers will bump their heads a few times. Really consider if a struct is the way to go, from the [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct):

"A structure type (or struct type) is a **value type** that can encapsulate data and related functionality. Typically, you use structure types to design small **data-centric** types that provide little or no behavior."

Consider this: if you had 2 values in your struct and you wanted to make constructors, would 2 or less constructors suffice? If the answer is no, then the answer is: don't use a struct.

Answer (score 1):

This is my take on this in case somebody finds it useful.

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public int item1;
    public float item2;
    public float item3;

    public static MyStruct Null => new MyStruct(-1, 0, 0);
}
```

I have a static method inside my struct so that I can do this:

```
var data = MyStruct.Null;
```

instead of

```
var data = new MyStruct();
data.item1 = -1;
...
```

Or create a custom constructor to pass the data.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is to override `ToString()`, e.g.

```
struct Test
{
    int num;
    string str;

    public override string ToString ()
    {
        return string.Format ($"{str} | {num}");
    }
}
```

As you have mentioned, it is impossible to define default values for fields other than default values for their appropriate types. However, with an overriden `ToString()`, you will see better formatted information about your structure in the console and during debugging.