# Default value in string property

Tags: c#

In the following `readonly struct`:

```
public readonly struct MyStruct
{
    public string MyString { get; } // default == null
    public string MyString2 { get => /*Can something be used here?*/ ?? String.Empty; }
}

var s = new MyStruct();
```

`MyString` would return `null`. I would like a way to have it return `String.Empty` instead when the default constructor was invoked. As the struct is `readonly`, no setter can be used, so I can't seem to use a backing field it seems.

To emphasize, this issue is really because a backing field cannot be used. If there is no way, that is fine, but if there is a way somehow to use a backing field (or something similar), that would be great.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a default value for the struct in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39846708/how-to-make-a-default-value-for-the-struct-in-c)

Comment: It is close, but it doesn't. The answer there mentions using a `setter`, but in this case, the struct is `readonly` - so no setters can be used.

Comment: @RufusL Thanks, but you cannot default initialize properties in structs.

Comment: you should just use your constructor to control the fallback value.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that this was for a struct before I commented! The linked duplicate has the answer.

Comment: @DanielA.White Thanks, but I am asking about the default constructor.

Comment: The default constructor for a struct will initialize all members of the struct to `default` (i.e., `null` for reference types (and nullable value types) and whatever zero-ish default value a value type has).  You cannot change that behavior

Comment: You may want to investigate creating an immutable class that has full value semantics (a la string).  Or, in this particular case, create a backing field for your `MyString2` property.  In the property getter, if the value is null, initialize it to something you want as the default.