# How to initialze a C# structure member to a number

Tags: c#

This is the defination of the structure.

```
struct Current
    { 
        public int NUMBER { get; set; }
        public int WD { get; set; }

    }
```

How can i initialize a member of the structure to a value while declaring the structure.

Something like

```
struct Current
        { 
            public int NUMBER { get; set; } = 0;
            public int WD { get; set; }
    
        }
```

Comment: Possible dublicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39846708/how-to-make-a-default-value-for-the-struct-in-c

Comment: You can make use of constructor.