# How to get default value for runtime object

Tags: c#, reflection

I did a little reflection code.

```
var objValue = objType.GetProperty(propertyName)!.GetValue(obj, null);
if (objValue == default) // doesn't work for structures
    continue;
```

But the equal operator doesn't work for structures. How to fix it?

Comment: Duplicate; read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39846708/how-to-make-a-default-value-for-the-struct-in-c and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572325/how-to-make-default-value-with-a-struct-property

Comment: These answers didn't help

Comment: This one helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325426